Warning using p0f and no output
I am trying to run p0f of some PCAP files and I am getting a warning and no output. Here is the full record:
me@my_laptop: ~$ p0f -r my_pcap.pcap -o p0f_output.txt

--- p0f 3.09b by Michal Zalewski <lcamtuf@coredump.cx> ---

[+] Closed 1 file descriptor.
[+] Loaded 322 signatures from '/etc/p0f/p0f.fp'.
[+] Will read pcap data from file 'my_pcap.pcap'.
[+] Default packet filtering configured [+VLAN].
[+] Log file '/mnt/pcap/p0f_output.txt' opened for writing.
[+] Processing capture data.

[!] WARNING: Unknown packet type 0, link detection issue?

All done. Processed 116 packets.

I am able to open this PCAP file in tcpdump and Wireshark. Is p0f expecting PCAP in a specific format? If so, how can I convert my PCAP to such a format?

Could you provide the pcap? And what OS you are running on? Was the pcap generated on the same OS?

I can't provide the pcap. I'm using p0f on Ubuntu 22. I don't know where/how the pcap was generated, but it was not generated on the same system.

But it works with tcpdump on the same system and the output from tcpdump actually makes sense (i.e. is the expected one)?

Yes, that's correct. If I run the command tcpdump -r my_pcap.pcap, I get human readable output that makes sense.

Maybe its pcapng format not pcap. Try converting with tcpdump -r my_pcap.pcap -w converted.pcap and then use converted.pcap instead with p0f.
`

Still getting the same output as before.
